# Getting average of product sales each day and calculate number of days that have positive sales

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have this table TARGETSALE that have the following columns

```
SELECT DATE, WEEK, BRANCH, PROD, TARGETREACH
FROM TARGETSALE
WHERE BRANCH = 1 
AND WEEK BETWEEN 52 AND 53;

DATE        WEEK    BRANCH  PROD    TARGETREACH
-------------------------------------------------------------------
01/09/2014  52      1       1        50 
02/09/2014  52      1       1       -10 
03/09/2014  52      1       1        50 
04/09/2014  52      1       1        50 
05/09/2014  52      1       1        40
06/09/2014  52      1       1       -10
07/09/2014  53      1       1        -5
08/09/2014  53      1       1         0
09/09/2014  53      1       1        10
10/09/2014  53      1       1        20
11/09/2014  53      1       1        30 
12/09/2014  53      1       1        40
13/09/2014  53      1       1         0
01/09/2014  52      1       2        20 
02/09/2014  52      1       2         0 
03/09/2014  52      1       2         0 
04/09/2014  52      1       2        10 
05/09/2014  52      1       2        20
06/09/2014  52      1       2        10
07/09/2014  53      1       2       -10
08/09/2014  53      1       2        10
09/09/2014  53      1       2       -10
10/09/2014  53      1       2        20
11/09/2014  53      1       2        20 
12/09/2014  53      1       2        40
13/09/2014  53      1       2         0
01/09/2014  52      1       3        30 
02/09/2014  52      1       3        30 
03/09/2014  52      1       3         5 
04/09/2014  52      1       3         0 
05/09/2014  52      1       3        10
06/09/2014  52      1       3       -10
07/09/2014  53      1       3       -10
08/09/2014  53      1       3       -10
09/09/2014  53      1       3        20
10/09/2014  53      1       3        10
11/09/2014  53      1       3        40 
12/09/2014  53      1       3        10
13/09/2014  53      1       3        10
```

"targetsales" shows how much over the target the sales is, where negative means how far below the target the sales was. How can I do the following:
1. I need to get the average for all the product for each day. Something like this:

```
    DATE        BRANCH  AVERAGE_SALES_OF_ALL_PRODUCT
    01/09/2014  1       33.33
    02/09/2014  1       -1.67 
    ...and so on
```

2. And then I need to have another query that shows how many days within those two weeks that there's positive average sales. Something like this:

   ```
   BRANCH  2WEEKS_SINCE    DAYS_WITH_POSITIVE_AVERAGE_SALES
   1       53              9
   ```

Above just an example not a real result.
Sorry, hope this not too confusing. Thank you so much.

Comment: Using SQL server instead of Oracle though. But it should work. First one - `select [date], branch, sum(targetreach)/COUNT(prod) as [avg]
from targetsale
group by [date], branch`

Comment: @BoratSagdiyev, Thanks! how bout the second one ? :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Oracle, the `date` type might still have a time component.  If you do not know if this is there, then use `trunc()` to remove it:

```
select trunc(date), branch, avg(targetreach)
from targetsale
group by truncdate, branch
order by 1, 2;
```

For the second query, you want to use `case`:

```
select branch, count(distinct case when targetreach > 0 then date end) as DaysWithPositiveSales
from targetsales
group by branch;
```

If you know there is one row per date per branch -- and the time component of the date is empty -- then the `distinct` is not necessary.

Answer (score 0):

1)

```
SELECT TRUNC(DATE, 'DD'), BRANCH, SUM(TARGETREACH) 
FROM TARGETSALE WHERE BRANCH = 1 AND WEEK BETWEEN 52 AND 53
GROUP BY TRUNC(DATE, 'DD'), BRANCH;
```

2)

```
SELECT BRANCH, SUM(DECODE(ABS(TARGETREACH), 1, 1, 0)
FROM TARGETSALE WHERE BRANCH = 1 AND WEEK BETWEEN 52 AND 53
GROUP BY BRANCH;
```